# How to filter a list according to date in templates in django

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model Volunteer in which I have a field 'registered_at = models.DateTimeField()'.
I am passing a list of Volunteer object to template.

I want to create a dropdown in template so that I can filter out the objects according to 'registered_at'. So basically I can list down Volunteers registered yesterday, today and so on.

In short, I have to group model objects according to data in template. So I have a date in template and all objects registered on that date below it.

I have considered all possible ideas and tempting to go towards jquery. Can anyone give some easy solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to natively do this in the template. However, you can **add a property to the model and access it in the template**.

*models.py* (on your Volunteer model; add as many as you like, i.e. )

```
from datetime import date

@property
def registered_today(self):
    if date.today() == self.date:
        return True
    return False
```

Then, *in your template*

```
<div class="
{% if volunteer_object.registered_today %}
    reg-today 
{% elif volunteer_object.registered_yesterday %}
    reg-yesterday
{% endif %}
    "> {{ volunteer_object }} </div>
```

Now, depending on what is selected for filtering, use JQuery to set div display properties. Set up a listener for each checkbox used for filtering and set `display: none` for the classes (such as 'reg-yesterday') that are not selected, `display: block` for those that are.

Comment: Thanks for your help..I have to group model object according to data in template? Is there a way or alternative. So I have date and all objects registered on that date stack below it.

Comment: I misunderstood at first... have edited my answer. I do not know of any Django modules that will take care of this, but jQuery would be pretty simple

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, filtering would be the next step. First I have to display the Volunteer objects according to date in template. I don't want any fancy things like yesterday, today. Just date and list of volunteers registered on that date

Comment: Grouping is easy, there's a few ways to do it. This page has a good example of implementing it. http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/03/django-group-list-by-date-in-templates.html

Comment: From there, I think that jquery to show/hide divs (wrapped around each grouping) based on id/class would be the way to go